# Solve $-1+B^{\prime}(r)r+B(r)=\frac{Q^2}{4 \pi r^2}$ analytically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $$-1+B^{\prime}(r)r+B(r)=\frac{Q^2}{4 \pi r^2}$$ , $Q=const$. The boundary condition is $B(r)\to 1$ as $r \to \infty$. I am faced with this equation while solving for the spherically symmetric metric with a charge $Q$. Though, I can find the solution using Mathematica, or Wolfram Alpha, I would like to get an analytic solution. I am familiar with techniques for solving ODEs not able to recall them.

Comment: By analytics solution you mean the process of ariving at the solution? See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a linear equation. Rewrite it as
$$
(r\,B)'=1+\frac{Q^2}{4\,\pi\,r^2}.
$$
Integrate to obtain
$$
r\,B=r-\frac{Q^2}{4\,\pi\,r}+C
$$
and
$$
B(r)=1-\frac{Q^2}{4\,\pi\,r^2}+\frac{C}{r}.
$$
The boundary condition is satisfied or any value of the constant $C$.

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thank you for sharing!